# Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to get a CSV with `fgetcsv()`, but I get an error like this:

> Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:..

If I `var_dump($handle)` for make sure then the output is : Bool(False)

```
<?php

    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
    //var_dump($handle);die;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        //print_r ($data);die;
        $import="INSERT into pickup_28(NO,TGL_PICKUP,SERVICE_NUMBER,ICCID,CUSTOMER_NAME,PRODUCT,ALAMAT,NO_ALT,AREA) 
        values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]')";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());

    }

?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the error message you don't understand. Since `fopen()` returns false there is some kind of error. Maybe the file doesn't exist anymore when you are asking for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to test whether `fopen` succeeded before you try to use the result:

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
if ($handle) {
    // Use $handle
} else {
    die("Unable to open file");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that `fopen()` function returned FALSE;

So you need modify your `fopen()` function also before using `fgetcsv(`) check if it is resoruce with `is_resource()` function. You can also check before opening if file is readable with function `is_readable()` or if exists with `file_exists()`