# how to import csv file data into mysql database using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller: partner.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Partner extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha', 'email'));
    }

    public function student()
    {
        if($this->input->post('save'))
        {
            $client_id[0]['client_id'] = $this->session->userdata('client_id');
            $radio = $this->input->post('class');
            $client = $client_id[0]['client_id'];


            $filename = $_FILES['students_list']['name'];

            $path = FCPATH."resources/imported_file/".$filename;
            $move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['students_list']['tmp_name'],$path.$_FILES['students_list']['name']);
            if($_FILES["students_list"]["size"] > 0)
            {
                $file = fopen($path, "r");
                while (($importdata = fgetcsv($file)))
                {
                    $data = array(
                        'firstname' => $importdata[0],
                        'email' =>$importdata[1],
                        'phone' =>$importdata[2],
                        'uploaded_date' => date('d-m-y'),
                        'twelfth_year' => date('Y'),
                        'client' => $client[0]['client_id'],
                        'class' => $radio
                    );
                    $this->db->insert('students',$data);
                }                    
                fclose($file);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('err_csv', '<p style="color: #87b87f;font-weight: bold;text-align:center;">Data are imported successfully..</p>');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('err_csv', '<p style="color: red;font-weight: bold;text-align:center;">Something went wrong..</p>');
            }
        }
    }
```

view:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file"  id="students_list"  name="students_list" accept=".csv" class="required">
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="save" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>
```

I have a csv file and I want to import csv file data into mysql database. But when I upload csv file and click on submit it generate error as show in image.

[image]

So, How can I remove this error ? please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Possible of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959422/warning-fgetcsv-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-c

Comment: use this CSV parse lib. https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

Answer (score 0):

you should use codeigniter file upload library for upload file and then use phpexcel library for import csv file.

Comment: Please mentioned this in comment.

Comment: you should use codeigniter file upload library for upload file and then use phpexcel library for import csv file.

Comment: @marmikpatel : Virb trying to tell you that, if you have solution in one line and without code demonstration, then please mention it in comments instead of mentioning as answer. So you have to comment under the question, and not on your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you can upload a file using upload library of CodeIgniter and $worksheet is an array your all data is stored in that array just print the worksheet.

```
class Excelreader_controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('upload');
    }

    function uploadFile()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|csv';     

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('uploadfile'))
        {
            $target_path = "upload/" . basename( $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]); 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
                $file=$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
                $csv_file="upload/".$file;
                $worksheet=array();
                if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) 
                {
                    $worksheet[] = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
                    {
                        $worksheet[]=$data;

                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                echo "not uploaded";
            }
        }
        else
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Partner extends CI_Controller 
 {
 function __construct() 
 {
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha', 'email'));
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('file');
}

public function student()
{
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {

if($_FILES['file']['name'])
                                {
                                    $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['students_list']['name']);

        if($filename[1] == 'csv')
                                    {

                                         $fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");

                                        while($data = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) 
                                         {
                                            for ($i = 0, $j = count($data); $i < $j; $i++)
                                            {   $item['firstname']=$data[0];
                                                $item['email'] =  $data[1];
                                                $item['phone'] =  $data[2];

                                                $item['uploaded_date'] = $data[3];
                                                $item['twelfth_year'] = $data[4];
                                                $item['client'] =  $data[5];
                                                $item['class'] =  $data[6];
                                            }
                                        $data = array('firstname' => $item['firstname'],
                                                'email' => $item['email'],
                                                      'phone' => $item['phone'],
                                                      'uploaded_date' => $item['uploaded_date'],
                                                      'twelfth_year' => $item['twelfth_year'] ,
                                                      'client' => $item['client'] ,
                                                      'class' => $item['class'], 

                                        $data['crane_features']=$this->db->insert('students',$data);

                                        }

                                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('FILE UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY')</script>";
                                    fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
                                    $data['success']="success";
                                    return $data;


                                    }
                                    }

                                    else{
                                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('TRY UPLOADING *.csv FILE')</script>";
                                            $this->load->view('uploadcssview');
                                        }
                                }

                        }
                    }
```

view file

```
     <form action = "<?php echo site_url('Partner/student'); ?>" 
       method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
          <center>
         <label>SELECT A CSV File:</label></center>

         <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-3"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4"><br/>
         <input type="file" name="file" id="file"  />
         </div>
         <br/>
         </form>

            <div class="col-md-1">
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Import" class="btn btn-
         info" />
          </div>
```